# Nuxt.js: Plugins client-side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to integrate [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in my Nuxt project. I keep getting this error, which I'm having a hard time resolving:

> Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$moment is not a function"

I'm implementing the module as a plugin.

*in* ***~/plugins/moment.js:***

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import * as moment from 'moment';

Vue.use(moment);

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    app.moment = moment;
    inject('moment', moment);
};
```

*in* ***nuxt.config.js:***

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/moment.js', ssr: false },
    ],
};
```

*in* ***~/pages/Page.vue:***

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ $moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }}
    </div>
</template>
```

It seems to be running fine on the client and I get expected results. I most often get the error when I refresh the page, so I suspect it has to do with nuxt failing to render the template on the server. I attempted to solve this then by wrapping the `div` in a `no-ssr` component but to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `import moment from 'moment';`?

Comment: In my plugin-file, yes I've tried that too!

Comment: I would suggest you try and see what $moment actually is (we know it is not a function but what is it?). It may be related to the injection or directly from the import of moment.

Comment: It seems to be undefined, that is when rendered on the server.

Comment: It's all good when run on the client, I *think* my problem is related to the SSR.

Comment: Um. Vue.use(moment) is for vue plugin. And momentjs isnt a vue plugin.  There several wrappers available 
https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment
https://github.com/julon/vue-moment-lib

Comment: Wait, I can only use vue plugins for Vue.use()?